# Change the Default " - Choose -" text in Ctools Jump menu?

Tags: blocks, chaos-tool-suite, 7

I've created a Ctools jump menu in a block in a module. The default text which Ctools provides for their jump menu is "- Choose -". Is there a way to change this in the module? I'm guessing it should happen somewhere in this line of code but not quite sure how to do it;

```
$form = ctools_jump_menu(array(), $form_state, array($url => t('Classified Ad'),$url2 => t('Places'),$url3 => t('Facility')), array());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a look at the ctools_jump_menu function's code [here](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!jump-menu.inc/function/ctools_jump_menu/7).
I would try the following:

```
$options = array( 'choose' => 'CUSTOM TEXT' );
$form = ctools_jump_menu(array(), $form_state, array($url => t('Classified Ad'),$url2 => t('Places'),$url3 => t('Facility')), $options);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ur very welcome!